# Header bold style removed after using HtmlContainerControl.InnerText property

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a page with a header like this:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;">
    <h3>bold text</h3>
</div>
```

Which  is rendered as bold indeed. But when I set the header text programmatically like this:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;">
    <h3 id="head3" runat="server">bold text</h3>
</div>
```

And the code behind:

```
head3.InnerText = "bold text";
```

, the header is no longer in bold. Why is that? I guess I'm missing some basic HTML concept...

Comment: That depends on your css. How are you setting bold to that header? by h3 selector or by id?

Comment: @Francisco Afonso , what do you mean by this? I'm new to HTML

Comment: Oh, nevermind, i see you dont have a css file, you're using style directly on html. You should style elements in css files, not in html.
Also the bold for font-weight attribute should be in h3 not the div and i think you dont need the semi-colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h3 style="font-weight:bold;">bold text</h3>
```

Or, you can set in C# code:

```
h3.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;");
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want this to apply on all the h3 set this in your CSS file:

```
h3{
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

this way you wont have to put it manualy on every h3